# Different sampling methods in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, bootstrap-4, dataset, weka, resampling

I have a unbalanced dataset. I try to balance it using different resampling methods. So far I know there are three methods to handle sampling. 1. Random sampling 2. cross validation 3. Bootstrap.

I am using Weka for data preprocessing. I know how to use cross validation in Weka. It comes with classifier like Random Forest or Naive bayes or any other.

But I did not find Random Sampling or Bootstrap.

I found supervised -> instances-> resample and unsupervised -> instances-> resample.

I would like to know the difference between two resample. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985391/what-is-the-difference-between-supervised-and-unsupervised-reampling-in-weka) is not very helpful.
How could I use Bootstap in Weka? Is there any options for that?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrapping isn't really an evaluation method within Weka.

See Eibe's reply on the Wekalist mailing a few years ago:

https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/thread/WIHQM6EK5HM4J4FHOOFNKDINK2EEWYZI/

Comment: Yeah I saw this link. Probably it was one of your previous reply as well. But resample did not work good to balance the data. So, what is your recommendation to balance the data?